# I am currently creating an anagram tester. The problem is that when i add two words that are the exact same it should print false but dosent

Tags: python

```
string1 = raw_input("What is the first word? (Case insensitive)\n")
string2 = raw_input("What is the second word? (Case insensitive)\n")

def anagrams(string1, string2):
    string1, string2 = string1.lower(), string2.lower()

    if len(string1) == len(string2):
            if set(string1) == set(string2) :
                return all([string1.count(c) == string2.count(c) for c in set(string1)])
    return False

print(anagrams(string1, string2))
```

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. Have you tested each line of your code and proven that your assertions are correct? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: why do you want `False` as the result for the same word twice? Unless you want to special-case this, 2 identical words *are* anagrams (they consist of the exactly the same letters).

Comment: anyway, you can always add an explicit check for the 2 words being identical and return `False` in this case

Comment: @RobinZigmond to my understanding i thought anagrams are the same letters but in a different order. therefore if they are the same it is not an anagran. i could be wrong :/

Comment: Depends on your definition, but as I said there's nothing wrong with making a special case for this. Because it *is* a special case. As I said above, just add a check for `if (string1 == string 2)` and `return False` in this case. Assuming everything else works properly (which it looks like it should from seeing your code), then that's all you need to do.

Comment: wow, that was all i needed, i feel stupid now but thank you @RobinZigmond

Comment: Seems like two words that are exactly the same *are* anagrams, no?

Comment: @ggorlen i guess there are different definitions of anagrams, but im not sure. my definiton is from google "a word, phrase, or name formed by rearranging the letters of another, such as spar, formed from rasp."

Answer (score 0):

It's the `if` statements that are causing it to perform this way. Let's say you give your function `"hello"` and `"hello"`. `len(string1)` *does* equal `len(string2)`, and the `set` of characters will be the same, returning `all([string1.count(c) == string2.count(c) for c in set(string1)])`. In this case, if you give it *different* words, it will `return False`

EDIT

Checking if the strings are explicitly equal will avoid this problem, and the `sets` being the same will tell you if they are anagrams:

```
if string1!=string2 and set(string1)==set(string2):
     # Do the rest
```

Comment: This will always return `False` for genuine anagrams - like eg. `star` and `rats`.

Answer (score 0):

Your anagram checker appears accurate as written. If you want to make a special case for identical words, you can add that check to your program by hand. Here's an example of adding the requirement that the letters must be rearranged:

```
from collections import Counter

def anagrams(a, b):
    return a != b and Counter(a) == Counter(b)
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/VelvetyDirectHarddrives)

Comment: thanks for the help, im quite new to python so this is great help to understand my code and more efficient and concrete ways of doing it